# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest does not work

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

Any idea why `sendSynchronousRequest` not work, and returns nil. Error and response is nil as well.

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://google.com")!
let ur = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
let response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?> = nil
let errorPtr = NSErrorPointer()
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(ur, returningResponse: response, error: errorPtr)
    if errorPtr != nil {
        var error: NSError = errorPtr.memory!
    }
})
```

## UPDATE

I tried in the async way:

```
var oq = NSOperationQueue()
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(ur, queue: oq, completionHandler: {response, data, error in

    let ii = 7
})
```

Here I get an error:

> (lldb) po error
>   Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo=0x1567f9d0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///http:/google.com, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///http:/google.com, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSUnderlyingError=0x15691880 "The requested URL was not found on this server."}

Strange google is not available?

Comment: Why use `sendSynchronousRequest` in `dispatch_async` when you can easily use `sendAsynchronousRequest:`?

Comment: Define "does not work". There are no `println()` debugging calls, did you put a breakpoint in after the `sendSynchronousRequest` call and examine the results?

Comment: In writing code and it does not work the best approach is to assume that it is the code one just wrote, not the system. That has worked well for me for several decades. Also reading error messages carefully usually provides good information, in this case: "NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///http:/google.com" is spot on.

Comment: I also often realize I made the mistake not system :)

Comment: In my case the error is mine over 99+% of the time. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `fileURLWithPath` and that will return the URL 
file:///private/var/folders/xs/6k9v2g217155wr9vgb3xrg_80000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.MyPlayground-F81D60A5-6797-4BEB-8AB9-2D156E2B6771/http:/google.com

What you need is `let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")!`
 and that will return the URL:
http://google.com